# Error in `getSymbols.^NSEI`(Symbols = NULL, env = NULL, verbose = FALSE, : could not find function "getSymbols.^NSEI"

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using `getSymbols` function from the quantmod package

If I do just

```
d <- getSymbols(
  Symbols = "^NSEI",
  from = Sys.Date()-3600,
  to = Sys.Date(),
  periodicity = "monthly",
  return.class = 'zoo',
  env = NULL
)
```

it works as expected i.e. I get data for NIFTY50 index

But if I use it in the function `DownloadStockData` written by me,

```
DownloadStockData(stocksList,
                  stocksDataPath,
                  fromDate = Sys.Date()-3600,
                  toDate = Sys.Date(),
                  freqStr = "monthly")

DownloadStockData <- function(stocksList, savePath, fromDate, toDate, freqStr){
  
  #stocksData <- list()
  
  #Download yahoo finance data
  for (i in 1:nrow(stocksList)){
    
    print(i)
    
    try({
      
    d <-  as.data.frame(
     
       tryCatch(
        expr =  {  
          getSymbols(
          
            Symbols = ifelse(
              substring(stocksList[i,1],1,1) == "^" | grepl(".BO", stocksList[i,1]),
              stocksList[i,1], 
              paste(stocksList[i,1] , ".NS", sep = "") 
            ),
            
            from = fromDate,
            to = toDate,
            periodicity = freqStr,
            return.class = 'zoo',
            env = NULL
          )
          
        }  #expr end

      )
    )
    
    write.csv(d, paste(savePath, "\\",stocksList[i,1] , ".csv", sep= "" ), row.names =FALSE)
  
    })
    
  } #end for loop

  
  
} #end function
```

I get error as,

> Error in getSymbols.^NSEI(Symbols = NULL, env = NULL, verbose =
> FALSE,  :    could not find function "getSymbols.^NSEI"

`DownloadStockData` function is working fine for other symbols like `TCS`, `INFY` etc. but faults on `^NSEI` symbol.

Comment: I encountered `Error in 1:nrow(stocksList) : argument of length 0` error while trying to run `DownloadStockData `

Comment: Why not use `lapply` if you want to get data from multiple stocks.